# GitHub History Changes on Every Commit

Tags: git, github, commit

So my team and I are having a very strange issue with Git / GitHub.
(a private repo)

Every time one of us commits, the commit history changes. This isn't a matter of different branches; at the moment, we're all pushing to master.

For instance, today, we took a look at the history and it said there were 62 commits on the master branch.
Then one of us pushed, and suddenly there were 55 commits.

What's worse, is the commits of the other person seemed to have vanished.

What I believe is happening is that we all have somehow gotten different histories in our local repos and thus when we push, it changes the entire history!

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?
Or perhaps what else the problem could be?

Edit

We are all definitely looking at the same repo, and we are not force pushing.

While my team and I have managed to get things back on track by starting a new repo and then adding our files carefully, I would still greatly appreciate a solution, or at least a plausible explanation as to why. As always, thank you.

Comment: Most likely you are looking at different repos.

Comment: Are people doing `git push -f`? They really shouldn't be.

Comment: Would you post some of the git log of different people's local repos? Git should be complaining if it can't advance the remote branch markers safely to match the local branch markers being pushed (i.e. move them forward along the same branch, i.e. without having to go backwards or backwards and down a different branch).

Comment: Force pushing altered history seems like the most plausible explanation to me. Are you using Git from the command line, or are you using a Git gui client?

Comment: I'm using eGit in Eclipse and the command line